# Google Search Results Page

Tags: wordpress, search, full-text-search, search-engine

Google Search Results shows different variations when searched the Website name with adding a space. I am Using WordPress Yoast Plugin.

Sometimes the results just show as a link and sometimes the results shows with the Inner Page Link details as well?

Does anyone can help what makes that happen?

See Attached Sample[image]

Answer (score 0):

The inner page links you are referring are called termed as **site-links** by google, and these site-links are picked up by google based on your website ranking/traffic/popularity the more old/famous your site the fast site-links will be picked-up by google.

The search result is depends on the search phrase you use, Google will always match the search term with the title of the site, if more close the match the higher probability of pulling the site links.

You can also user google search console to demote the links to appear in google search.

And the Yoast SEO plugin will give you the options to title,describe,keyword every post and page of wordpress site, but this plugin/ any other plugins have no direct effect on this site links.